# Doing a certain action after pressing the Enter key -React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, keyboard-events, textinput

I am using react-native-phone-input package for entering phone number. I want the password field below to open when the user presses the enter key on the keyboard after entering the phone number. There is no such method in the package. How can I do that? Can I just listen for the enter key when the keyboard is turned on and make it go to password input?

```js
import { TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PhoneInput from 'react-native-phone-input';

export default function SignUp({ navigation }) {

  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('');

  return (
    <View >
      <PhoneInput
        ref={ref => { phone = ref }}
        onChangePhoneNumber={setPhoneNumber}
        style={{ width: 150, height: 30, backgroundColor: 'grey' }}
      />
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={setPassword}
        value={password}
        style={{ width: 150, height: 30, backgroundColor: 'grey', marginTop: 20 }}
      />
    </View >
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `prop` in [react-native-phone-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-phone-input) that should allow you to handle this as you would with a normal `TextInput`.

> onPressConfirm
> func  none
> handler to be called when taps the confirm button

Thus, you can define a state and use the `onPressConfirm` function prop to change this state. Then use conditional rendering to hide or show the `password` input.

```js
import { TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PhoneInput from 'react-native-phone-input';

export default function SignUp({ navigation }) {

  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('');
  const [confirm, setConfirm] = useState(false)

  return (
    <View >
      <PhoneInput
        ref={ref => { phone = ref }}
        onChangePhoneNumber={setPhoneNumber}
        style={{ width: 150, height: 30, backgroundColor: 'grey' }}
        onPressConfirm={() => setConfirm(true)}
      />
      { confirm &&
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={setPassword}
        value={password}
        style={{ width: 150, height: 30, backgroundColor: 'grey', marginTop: 20 }}
      />}
    </View >
  );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the onPressConfirm works after selecting the flag. I want to start typing in the  password input field after pressing the enter key on the keyboard when entered a phone number.